# ruby: validating https urls

Tags: ruby, url

Actually i'm  using that one for validating https urls:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
      response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
        http.head(uri.path)
      end
      response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess) || response.is_a?(Net::HTTPRedirection)
```

Exists a similar solution for https url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `use_ssl` option. Details is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS).